# why hasPrevious() method can not be called directly

Tags: java

I dont understand why hasPrevious method does not work when I delete hasNext() method..Are they related to each other somehow?So my question is that why I cant call hasprevious method directly just after call Listiterator interface

```
 List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ListIterator<Integer> itr = null;
    li.add(22);
    li.add(44);
    li.add(88);
    li.add(11);
    li.add(33);
    itr = li.listIterator();
    System.out.println("In reverse order :");
    System.out.println(itr.hasPrevious());
    while (itr.hasPrevious()) {
        System.out.print(""+itr.previous());
    }
```

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Please provide a [MRE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to start navigating from the end to the beginning, declare your `ListIterator` as follows:

```
ListIterator<Integer> itr = list.listIterator(li.size());
```

This will point the iterator at the end from where you can navigate backwards.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> li = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        ListIterator<Integer> itr = li.listIterator(li.size());
        while (itr.hasPrevious()) {
            System.out.println(itr.previous());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

If you start from the beginning of the list and move forward, you can always go back using `previous` e.g.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> li = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        ListIterator<Integer> itr = li.listIterator();
        System.out.println("Moving forward:");
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }
        System.out.println("Moving backward:");
        while (itr.hasPrevious()) {
            System.out.println(itr.previous());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Moving forward:
1
2
3
4
5
Moving backwards:
5
4
3
2
1
```

**TL;DR** The iterator does not move back if it is already at the beginning. Similarly, the iterator does not move forward if it is already at the end.

Check [this](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java) for the code.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I wonder why code above worked when i add hasNext and iterate,and hasPrevioous worked.What is the difference between hasNext and hasPrevious?

Comment: @SamirAllahverdiyev Note how in his iterator he actually defined the size, i think what you had missing is the lack of a size so the iterator initially had nothing stored. Thus when u did next it and then reverse it worked since it added that in. That is my guess; haven't coded in java for a while

Comment: But when I do not define size, my hasNext method work correctly..and hasPrevious work only after defining hasNext,and After defining size ,my hasNext did not work.I would like to know what is the reason behind it?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Yeap I got it .But my question is that what is happening there internally? and in my code If i add hasNext and iterate before hasPrevious,it will work.What is the magic behind it?